# Superscripts appear in various weird places in fractions

Tags: math-mode, superscripts, fractions

This is a weird phenomenon.

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  $$Z^* \frac{Z^*}{Z^*}$$
\end{document}
```

It produces the following picture:

[image]

The asterisks appear in various places in comparison to the ***Z***. This looks particularly bad in the denominator. Any idea what's behind this?

Comment: Unrelated but you should use `\[ ... \]` instead of `$$ ... $$`. There are several threads covering the reason.

Comment: the  denominator use a "cramped" style to avoid spreading things out too much (this is built in to tex the program although the exact amount superscripts are raised in normal and cramped styles are in settable fontdimen parameters)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There's nothing weird about the placement of the three superscript asterisks. They are placed at different heights because they occur in three distinct math styles. (Aside: TeX has 8 possible math styles. See p. 140f. in the TeXbook for more information about these 8 styles.)

- in the first term, TeX is in (uncramped) display style, labelled `D` in the TeXbook;
- in the numerator term, TeX is in (un-cramped) text style, labelled `T` in the TeXbook; and
- in the denominator term, TeX is in cramped text style, labelled `T'` in the TeXbook.

I assume you like the first look the best. If that's the case, you could write

```
\[ Z^* \frac{\displaystyle Z^*}{\displaystyle Z^*} \]
```

to force all three `Z^*` terms to have the same look.

Alternatively, you could set up a macro named, say, `\ddfrac`, as follows:

```
\newcommand\ddfrac[2]{\frac{\displaystyle #1}{\displaystyle #2}}
```

and then write

```
\[ Z^* \ddfrac{Z^*}{Z^*} \]
```

in the body of the text.

A small MWE: the item on the left shows the result of your original code, and the item on the right shows the output when using the `\ddfrac` macro:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\ddfrac[2]{\frac{\displaystyle #1}{\displaystyle #2}}
\begin{document}
$\displaystyle 
Z^*\frac{Z^*}{Z^*} \quad Z^*\ddfrac{Z^*}{Z^*}$
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*, inspired by David Carlisle's comment: pdfLaTeX provides four directives related to math style: `\displaystyle`, `\textstyle`, `\scriptstyle`, and `\scriptscriptstyle`. (The code above uses only one of these directives -- `\displaystyle`.) If you happen to use LuaLaTeX, you could employ four additional style-related directives: `\crampeddisplaystyle`, `\crampedtextstyle`, `\crampedscriptstyle`, and `\crampedscriptscriptstyle`. E.g., if you wanted to impose the "cramped text style look" on the numerator term of `\frac`, you could define a new macro as follows -- "ct" stands for "**c**ramped **t**ext style":

```
\newcommand\ctfrac[2]{\frac{\crampedtextstyle #1}{\crampedtextstyle #2}}
```

---

*Second Addendum*, prompted by @daleif's comment: The `mathtools` package provides a directive called `\cramped`, which typesets its argument in the cramped version of the applicable uncramped math style. Using the `mathtools` package, then, one would write the preceding `\ctfrac` macro as follows:

```
\newcommand\ctfrac[2]{\frac{\cramped[\textstyle]{#1}}{\cramped[\textstyle]{#2}}}
```

Comment: nice answer, for completeness you could mention that luatex has `\crampeddisplaystyle\crampedtextstyle\crampedscriptstyle\crampedscriptscriptstyle` should you really need to force one of the cramped styles.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Thanks for this suggestion; I've provided an addendum to flesh out what might be done with `\crampedtextstyle`, etc.

Comment: `mathtools` also have some cramped support

Comment: @daleif - Thanks for this suggestion; I've provided a second addendum to show how `\cramped` might be used in the definition of `\ctfrac`.

Answer (score 13):

If a fraction appears when display style is in force, the numerator will use text style and the denominator will use “cramped” text style; similarly, the numerator and the denominator will be one style level below the starting one, with the denominator in the “cramped” variety.

The cramped variety of a math style uses less high superscript than the uncramped one, in order they don't clash with the fraction line or the vinculum in radicals (also using the cramped variety).

You can define a `\ufrac` command (uncramped fraction):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ufrac}[2]{% uncramped fraction
 \frac{#1}{\mathpalette\ufrac@den{#2}}%
}
\newcommand{\ufrac@den}[2]{#1#2}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
Z^* \frac{Z^*}{Z^*}
\quad
Z^* \ufrac{Z^*}{Z^*}
\]
\[
\textstyle
Z^* \frac{Z^*}{Z^*}
\quad
Z^* \ufrac{Z^*}{Z^*}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd avoid forcing display style. In case you'd like to, here's a way

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ufrac}[2]{% uncramped fraction
 \frac{\mathpalette\ufrac@style{#1}}
      {\mathpalette\ufrac@style{#2}}%
}
\newcommand{\ufrac@style}[2]{%
  \ifx\textstyle#1\displaystyle\else#1\fi#2%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
Z^* \frac{Z^*}{Z^*}
\quad
Z^* \ufrac{Z^*}{Z^*}
\]
\[
\textstyle
Z^* \frac{Z^*}{Z^*}
\quad
Z^* \ufrac{Z^*}{Z^*}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: While I can certainly appreciate the recommendation to avoid forcing the `\displaystyle`, this result, like barbara's, does not set all three asterisks uniformly.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I don't think it matters.

Comment: I agree that it wouldn't bother me, but it seems it bothered the OP.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I provided the solution also for the case.

Answer (score 5):

david carlisle's comment gives the reason.  here's a way to "fix" it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \[Z^* \frac{Z^*}{Z_{\mathstrut}^*}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Even that doesn't quite "fix" it. (The non-fractioned asterisk rises above the top of the `Z`, whereas the other asterisks align to the top of the `Z`)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes that isn't really the main issue but the numerator and denominator still have different settings, the denominator is set still in cramped style but slightly higher because of the strut, any similarity to the uncramped setting in the numerator is accidental (and font dependent).