# Bad spacing of exponents in denominator

Tags: superscripts, fractions

Please look at the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\Huge

\begin{equation}
\frac{x^{2}}{x^{2}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
x^{2} / x^{2}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Can you see the wrong placement of the exponent in the denominator? Compare it to the flat fraction.

[image: output of example code]

I do not really have an idea what to do to get the same spacing. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Denominators use the “cramped” style, where exponents are lower than in the “uncramped” style used in the numerator. At `\Huge` size the effect is more evident than in `\normalsize`.

Comment: potential duplicate: [Superscripts appear in various weird places in fractions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/337328/579)

Comment: Is there a way to switch off the cramped style globaly?

Comment: @user125730 - Cramped style for the denominator terms of fractions is "hard-wired", i.e., built into the algorithms of all TeX engines.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - I wouldn't consider the earlier posting to be a good forerunner of the present query, which appears to be focused exclusively on differences in the placement of the exponents across numerator and denominator. Imposing `\displaystyle` on both numerator and denominator (the solution proposed in the earlier posting) does "work" here, but only because the exponent positions happen to be the same in cramped and uncramped display style. However (as I know you know too), using `\displaystyle` instead of `\textstyle` affects a whole lot more than just the exponents' positions.

Comment: @Mico -- i was thinking particularly of egreg's answer.  using `\displaystye` is potentially disastrous; i'd never use that.  what i *would* use is `x^2_{\vphantom{0}}` to get a pseudo-subscript with a good height and zero depth, which forces the superscript to visually the same place as in the "in line" form.  maybe i should offer that as another answer.

Comment: @Mico: I repeat, the exponent position is *not* the same in cramped and uncramped display style: try `\[x^{2} \overline{x^{2}}\]`, or read (carefully! :-) the last two lines on p. 445 of _The TeXbook_.  BTW, thanks for your suggestion of showing the effects of `\LeveledExponentsForCurrentSize` on fractions: I’ll update my answer shortly.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti - Thanks. My apologies for not expressing myself perfectly clearly in my comment directed at barbara b. Consider `\[\frac{\displaystyle x^{\!2}Y^{\!*}}{\displaystyle x^{\!2}Y^{\!*}}\]`. The positions of the exponents (1`2` and `*`, resp.) sure look like they don't depend on whether they occur in the numerator or the denominator. (In case you're wondering where this code snippet would come from: It's copied from the posting to which barbara b. provided a link.)

Comment: @Mico: Thanks for your reply.  It looks like I had understood exactly the opposite of what you meant. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before reading on, please see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/337334/69818).  What follows is about modifying TeX’s behavior so to obtain the desired output at the *primitive* level (in particular, not just for fractions, but for all occurences of a “cramped” style).

It is true what @Mico says in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357998/bad-spacing-of-exponents-in-denominator#comment881808_357998), that is, that cramped style for denominators is a very low-level feature built into all TeX engines; but it is also true that it can be configured by means of the relevant `\fontdimen` parameters (so that I wouldn’t describe it as being “hard-wired”).  The exact meaning of these parameters is defined in Appendix G of *The TeXbook*; in particular, what is relevant for this question is just the second sentence of Rule 18c (last two lines on p. 445), which dictates how TeX chooses the amount by which “ordinary” exponents (that is, not too deep) are to be raised when applied to “ordinary” base symbols (for example, single characters, as opposed to subformulas).  It turns out that there are three possibilities:

- in `\displaystyle`, the chosen amount is the value of the parameter
  that can be referred to as `\fontdimen 13 \textfont 2`;
- in any “uncramped”, non-display style, the chosen amount is the value
  of `\fontdimen 14 \<style>font 2`
- in any “cramped” (either display or non-display) style, the chosen
  amount is `\fontdimen 15 \<style>font 2`, except that `<style>` is
  substituted with `text` if it is `display`.

As it has already been pointed out by others, “cramped” styles are used for denominators of fractions; note, though, that they are used also in radicals, in `\overline` constructions, and still in other places.

As a consequence, it is possible to “disable”, virtually, the “cramped” styles simply by assigning to the 15th `\fontdimen` parameter the value of the 14th, thereby rising exponents in denominators by the same amount that TeX ordinarily uses for exponents in numerators; that is, exactly the opposite of what @Mico’s solution, which forces a “cramped” style in the numerators too, does.

However, there are some caveats.

1. First of all, changes to `\fontdimen` parameters do ***not*** obey
   TeX grouping rules: their scope is ***always*** global
   (*The TeXbook*, p. 277).  This means that, if you want to undo them,
   you need to save the original values “by hand”.
2. In the second place, each `\fontdimen` change should be repeated
   thrice (once for each style, that is, for `\textfont 2`,
   `\scriptfont 2`, and `\scriptscript 2`), unless you want to disable
   “crampedness” only for some styles but not for others: for example,
   in order to disable “crampedness” only for `\textstyle` and
   `\scriptstyle`, but not for `\scriptscriptstyle`, you would change
   `\fontdimen 15 \textfont 2` and `\fontdimen 15 \scriptfont 2`,
   but not `\fontdimen 15 \scriptscriptfont 2`.
3. This triple setting, in turn, must be repeated for all the sizes
   (`\normalsize`, `\footnotesize`, …) at which you are typesetting
   formulas, since, in general, the font that corresponds to, say,
   `\textfont 2` in `\normalsize` is not the same one that corresponds
   to `\textfont 2` in `\footnotesize`.
4. If you decide to suppress “crampedness”, it seems wise to suppress
   “displayedness” too, that is, to give the same value as
   `\fontdimen 14` to `\fontdimen 13` as well (see above).

The following code gives a sort of “proof of concept”.  It defines two declarations, both of which are irreversible:

- `\LeveledExponentsForCurrentSize` suppresses both “crampedness”
  and “displayedness” for the current font size only (but all the way
  to `\scriptscriptstyle`);
- `\LeveledExponentsForAllSizes`suppresses both “crampedness”
  and “displayedness” for all the *standard* LaTeX sizes;
  note, however, that this will load a large number of math fonts,
  most of which you are never going to use, and which might cause you
  to hit the limit for the number of loadable fonts in certain engines
  (mainly, in pdfTeX).

As already hinted, the code makes no provision for saving the original values, and hence for reverting to the original setting.  This isn’t difficult to accomplish, however.

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\makeatletter

\newcommand*\@level@exponents@for@font[1]{%
    \fontdimen 13 #1\tw@ \fontdimen 14 #1\tw@
    \fontdimen 15 #1\tw@ \fontdimen 14 #1\tw@
}
\newcommand*\@level@exponents@for@size[1]{%
    \begingroup
        #1% set font size
        \setbox\z@ \hbox{$$}% activate math font for that size
        \@level@exponents@for@font \textfont
        \@level@exponents@for@font \scriptfont
        \@level@exponents@for@font \scriptscriptfont
    \endgroup
}
\newcommand*\LeveledExponentsForCurrentSize{%
    \@level@exponents@for@size \@currsize
}
\newcommand*\LeveledExponentsForAllSizes{%
    \@level@exponents@for@size \tiny
    \@level@exponents@for@size \scriptsize
    \@level@exponents@for@size \footnotesize
    \@level@exponents@for@size \small
    \@level@exponents@for@size \normalsize
    \@level@exponents@for@size \large
    \@level@exponents@for@size \Large
    \@level@exponents@for@size \LARGE
    \@level@exponents@for@size \huge
    \@level@exponents@for@size \Huge
}



\begin{document}

\Huge

Compare $x^{2}$ with $\overline{x^{2}}$.
In display, three placements are possible:
\[x^{2}|{\textstyle x^{2}}|\overline{x^{2}}\]

As @Mico suggests, let's show fractions too, both in display, as in
\[\frac{x^{2}}{x^{2}}\ne x^{2},\]
and inline: \( \frac{x^{2}}{x^{2}}\ne x^{2} \).

\LeveledExponentsForCurrentSize

Now compare them again: \( x^{2}|\overline{x^{2}} \).
Now in display:
\[x^{2}|{\textstyle x^{2}}|\overline{x^{2}}\]
And the fractions, displayed
\[\frac{x^{2}}{x^{2}}\ne x^{2},\]
and inline: \( \frac{x^{2}}{x^{2}}\ne x^{2} \).

\end{document}
```

For your convenience, here is the resulting output:

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: +1. Thanks for pointing out that it's possible to change from cramped to uncramped style in denominators and hence that the default setting isn't truly hardwired (as I had incorrectly claimed in a comment). A minor suggestions: In order to address the OP's concern more directly, it might be useful to show how `$\frac{x^2}{x^2}$` looks like before and after executing `\LeveledExponentsForCurrentSize`, with `\frac` occurring in both display and text style.

Comment: @Gustavo Mezzetti: I am really impressed and your solution works fine but not for LuaLaTeX... Is ther a possibility to make it work in LuaLaTeX?

Comment: @user125730: I’m sorry, but I can barely say that I have finally (almost) completed the study of the original TeX engine by Knuth—well, no, also with e-TeX extensions.  With pdfTeX I’ve pretty worked my way up to an acceptable level of knowledge, and only recently I began tackling XeTeX; but a serious study of LuaTeX is still beyond the horizon of my foreseeable “to-do” list… ;-)  However, [Mico’s answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/337332/69818) to the question that Barbara Beeton cites contains some hints for LuaTeX.

Answer (score 6):

To force the so-called "cramped" style on exponents in both the numerator and the denominator, use the `\cramped` macro -- which is provided by the `mathtools` package -- on the term(s) in the numerator. ("Cramped style is in force automatically for the denominator.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for "\cramped" macro
\begin{document}
$\displaystyle\frac{x^2+\cramped{x^2}}{x^2} $
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

my preference is to choose a method that has no side effects elsewhere.
that eliminates the method described (most excellently!) by gustavo mezzetti.
and since forcing the "cramped" style is not what was asked for (and would
have the side effect that if the modified object is near a variable that has
both sub- and superscript), the alignment would not be consistent.

a method that operates on only the position of the superscript is to insert
a phantom subscript.  this pushes up the superscript to *almost* the level of
the superscript on a normal, in-line variable.  this can be made into a command,
as it is here, for convenience.  the phantom object should have a good height
and no depth; a digit or capital "X" is usually a good choice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\matchsupheight}{_{\vphantom{0}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
x^{2} / x^{2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{x^{2}}{x^{2}} \quad \frac{x^{2}}{x\matchsupheight^{2}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]