# How can I switch off the cramped style in LuaLaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, luatex, fractions

Please look at the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{fontspec,unicode-math}

\begin{document}

\Huge

\begin{equation}
\frac{x^{2}}{x^{2}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
x^{2} / x^{2}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As usual the denominator is printed ugly in the cramped style. With pdfTeX it is possible to switch off the cramped style as shown here:

[Bad spacing of exponents in denominator](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357998/bad-spacing-of-exponents-in-denominator)

(Look at Gustavo Mezzetti's post.)

I would like to find such a solution for LuaLaTeX, so I read its manual (pages 84ff.):

http://www.luatex.org/svn/trunk/manual/luatex.pdf

I found some hints:

```
\Umathsupshiftup\crampeddisplaystyle=\the\Umathsupshiftup\textstyle
\Umathsupshiftup\crampedtextstyle=\the\Umathsupshiftup\textstyle
```

I added these lines, but the result is still the same. What do I make wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You don't mention this explicitly, but I'm assuming that you want to disable cramped style mainly for fraction terms. If that's the case, here's a solution that works with pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, and LuaLaTeX: define variant forms of the `dfrac` and `\tfrac` macros that use uncramped math style for the denominators.

In the following screeshot, output of the "regular" forms of `\dfrac` and `\tfrac` are shown on the left, and output of the variant forms is shown on the right. Speaking for myself, I very much prefer the output of the "regular" forms; your opinion may differ...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\newcommand{\mydfrac}[2]{{\dfrac{#1}{\textstyle #2}}}
\newcommand{\mytfrac}[2]{{\tfrac{#1}{\scriptstyle #2}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\dfrac{x^{2}}{x^{2}} + \mydfrac{x^{2}}{x^{2}} \\
\tfrac{x^{2}}{x^{2}} + \mytfrac{x^{2}}{x^{2}}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```