# \prime position too low, if in \frac denominator

Tags: math-mode, libertine

If used in the denominator, the `\prime` symbols are lower than in the numerator. This becomes even more pronounced (and annoying) if Libertine/Libertinus Math is used.

Why is that? Can this somehow be corrected?

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}

\begin{document}

  \begin{equation}
    \frac{h^{\prime\prime}-h^{\prime}}{h^{\prime\prime}-h^{\prime}}
  \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Default CM:

[image]

`libertinust1math`:

[image]

Comment: For a one-shot-only solution you can just add `\textstyle` in the denominator. Or do you want to avoid cramped styles altogether? That's tough, cramped styles are hard coded in TeX...

Comment: Could you give an example? I wonder why this isn't handled correctly in a math-centred typesetting software like TeX.

Comment: Well, it _is_ handled correctly from `TeX`'s point of view. See [this questions and its answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/337328/82917). (This might actually be a dupe.)

Comment: I would expect whatever styles TeX provides, the same ones to be used in the numerator as in the denominator. Could you please briefly summarize what the reason is behind this weirdness? (I have no The TeX Book.)

Comment: Sorry, beats me. All I can say is "that's how Knuth wrote TeX". Hopefully someone with more information will step in.

Comment: So let me thank you for the link to the other question you gave in your 2nd comment.

Comment: I will add `\let\fracorig\frac\renewcommand\frac[2]{\fracorig{\displaystyle #1}{\displaystyle #2}}` to the current and to all my future documents. Let's see which side-effects it may have.

Comment: That will have very bad side effects. All fractions in text mode will be broken, as well as fractions in numerators/denominators of other fractions.

Comment: Yes, you are right, not such a good idea in the case of nested fractions.

Comment: why are you using `h^{\prime}` rather than `h'` (it makes no difference really but you almost never need to use `\prime`)

Answer (score 3):

The amount superscripts are raised is determined by the fontdimen parameters of the font specified for fam2. In the case of the denominator it's mostly fontdimen15.

Here I set 13,14,and 15 to a rather large value and you see the numerator and denominator then match

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}

\begin{document}
$a$
\fontdimen13 \textfont2 =7pt
\fontdimen14 \textfont2 =7pt
\fontdimen15 \textfont2 =7pt
  \begin{equation}
    \frac{h^{\prime\prime}-h^{\prime}}{h^{\prime\prime}-h^{\prime}}
  \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88991/what-do-different-fontdimennum-mean/88993#88993

Answer (score 2):

You seem to not want the cramped style in the denominator:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}

\newcommand{\ncfrac}[2]{\frac{#1}{\mathpalette\notcramped{#2}}}
\newcommand{\notcramped}[2]{#1#2}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\ncfrac{h''-h'}{h''-h'}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac{h''-h'}{h''-h'}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't seem to understand your code. Where, in the first `\newcommand`,  is the second argument to be passed to `\notcramped`?

Comment: @AlexG `\mathpallete` executes the command four times supplying the "missing" argument in each case as `#1` (`\displaystyle`, then `\textstyle`, then `scriptstyle` and `\scriptscriptstyle`)