# Vertical spacing of \circ used for degree within \frac

Tags: typography, superscripts, fractions, vertical-spacing, degrees

I noticed the different vertical spacing of `\circ` used for degree within `\frac` command.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[ \frac{180^\circ}{180^\circ} \]
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Using `{180}^\circ` resolves the "issue", though.

1. Isn't `\circ` in MWE applied to a box containing only `0`, which should be as equal as high as box containing `180`?
2. Why does `180^\circ` get rendered differently in numerator and denominator?

Comment: I don't really know the details of the spacing rules in math mode, but I'd say your premise is wrong that only the height of the `0` determines the vertical position of the exponent. As a practical note I'd recommend _always_ typesetting any numerical values (except small integers), especially those with units, using [`siunitx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx): `\frac{\ang{180}}{\ang{180}}`

Comment: in the denominator cramped style is used. See eg. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/337332/2388

Comment: So, the behavior is "by design", and I should probably stick with the simpler code? Thanks! @UlrikeFischer Your comment is actually the answer since my question could be considered as duplicate.