# Bracket size in fraction differs between numerator and denominator

Tags: equations

I need the following formula (simplified):

```
\frac{\left( e^l \right) }{\left( e^l \right) }
```

I get (from https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php and similar in my code):

[image]

I did not expect these parenthesis to have different size. It seems to be connected to the superscript l somehow.

Is this intended? Can I change this somehow to have the same size?

Comment: In your example, you can replace the pair `\left( \right)` with `\bigl( \bigr)`. In your real formula, if necessary , you also have the `\Bigl/r, \biggl/r, \Biggl/r` series.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks, that is a workaround I can use. But shouldn't `\left` and `\right` choose the (right) size independent of being numerator or denominator?

Comment: Very often, it is better to choose the size manually. Further, you can have line breaks or `&` in long or aligned equations with  these \bigl, &c., which you cannot with `\left \right`.

Comment: The reason for the different treatment of numerator and denominator in fractions is explained in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/337334).  (And really, it's not necessary to use the "larger" parentheses in this situation.  The regular parentheses cover the expression adequately, and won't be misunderstood.)

Comment: Ok, that's an explanation though I'm not sure I like the behaviour. I thought using left/right would spare me to decide every time which parantheses are the right. But apparently I have to fine tune a bit.